# Where I can find the complete list of SpaCy Dependency Parsing labels or annotations?

Tags: nlp, dependencies, spacy, text-parsing

I have try to refer to spaCy official website https://spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing
but I only got list of universal dependency relation which also on https://universaldependencies.org/u/dep/

while, when I try to parse some sentences, I also got labels or annotations that not have been listed. Such as: *prep, dative,* and *dobj*, even though that those labels can be associated with preposition for *prep*, direct object for *dobj*, and ??? for *dative*.

[image]

Is there any reference for me to find the complete list of SpaCy Dependency Parsing labels or annotations?

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the [SpaCy documentaion](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing), English and German use different sets of labels than UD. For English, these are [ClearNLP labels](https://github.com/clir/clearnlp-guidelines/blob/master/md/specifications/dependency_labels.md).

Comment: Thank you very much @Jindřich just hardly find that list by myself, really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 7):

You can get an overview of all labels by browsing to the respective model page in the documentation, e.g. https://spacy.io/models/en#en_core_web_lg and expanding the section "Label scheme".

On this page, it also mentions which corpus was used to train, in this case [OntoNotes 5](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T19). This is where the labelset comes from.

Further, you can run `spacy.explain` to try and get more information:

```
print(spacy.explain("prep"))
```

gives you

> prepositional modifier